# Display tag excerpt when asking a question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, asking-questions

I have seen a few posts that highlight the fact that the some tags are being used incorrectly e.g. [this question here regarding the assembly tag.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74629/148203)

What about the idea of displaying the tag excerpt on the Ask Question page? With some text along the lines of of "These are tags you have chosen, are you sure about this?"

When tags are input the relevant tag excerpt (if available) would be retrieved. The excerpt could be displayed either below the tag input box or down the left hand side pane. Some kind of loading indicator could be displayed to let the user know something is happening.

This could at least alert the user to the fact they may be inadvertently choosing the wrong tag.

Comment: +1 for showing it in the right bar; it's fairly empty when asking questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, we now show **a live tag preview in the question ask page preview** per https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/

[image: Screenshot from blog]

Comment: Though [you don’t see anything](http://i.imgur.com/RhbtpR8.png) if you came to the page with the tag preselected via, e.g., [`tags=c%23`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=c%23). Granted, if you got such a link, you probably chose the right tag. But you won’t see any of the “don’t ask these questions on this tag!” advice if that’s in the tag wiki.